# Openssl and Node's Crypto have different outputs

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography

in short, I want to `sign` a string(`"a"`) just like `openssl` using `crypto` library in node. but I get wrong output over and over again.

### Long Description

#### signing with openssl

I have two generated rsa keys : `public-key.pem` and `private-key.pem` that I have made them with openssl :

```
$ openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem
$ openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout >public-key.pem
```

when I type these in shell:

```
$ echo "a" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature_openssl.bin
```

It generates a file named `siganture_openssl.bin`.

#### signing with node crypto

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256')
const fs = require('fs')
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private-key.pem', 'utf8')

sign.write("a")
sign.end()
let res = sign.sign(privateKey, 'binary')
fs.writeFileSync('./signature_node.bin', res, 'binary')
```

this block generates a file named `signature_node.bin`.

#### verifying generated binaries

to verify generated signatues, I do:

```
$ echo "a" | openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature_openssl.bin -verify public-key.pem
Verified OK
```

but node doesn't verify :

```
$ echo "a" | openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature_node.bin -verify public-key.pem
Verification Failure
```

the question is: what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: In node you signed a string consisting of the letter a, but in OpenSSL you both signed and are trying to verify a string consisting of the letter a PLUS A NEWLINE. That is different data, and the purpose of a signature is to verify the same data but not different data. Assuming non-ancient Unix, try `printf %s "a"` (you don't actually need the quotes in this case but may in others). PS: you've misspelled the `signature_` filenames two different ways, but I assume that's just a mistake in posting and your actual files are correct.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you that solved my problem. If you answer the question I will accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Use `echo -n` unless you want the newline. Or, add a newline to your Node.js code. On Linux the newline is `LF`. Also see [`echo` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: [OpenSSL create SHA hash from shell stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066171/608639), [OpenSSL string decryption issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17117687/608639), [Encrypt a string using openssl command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10106771/608639), etc.